# Converting a Spring Application's main class to an application runner causes un-scanned beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud

I am trying to implement a Spring Boot Application. Initially the entry point of the application was a plain java class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. The main function of this class looked like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Everything worked fine in this setting and Spring scanned all the sub-packages for beans. Beans were written for `spring-cloud`, and thus are not autowired.

Because of a certain need, I had to rewrite the main application class as an `ApplicationRunner`. This is how the new class looked -

```
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

  @Autowired
  public Application(final Property property) {
    runService =
        Boolean.parseBoolean(
            property.getEnable());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(final ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    if (runService) {
      SpringApplication.exit(context);
      log.info("Exiting!");
    } else {
      log.info("Running!");
    }
  }
}
```

However there is a problem with this new implementation. The Spring is now unable to find beans which are defined in sub-packages. I couldn't use `@ComponentScan` since that requires atleast one autowired bean.

All of my attempts to get Spring to scan all beans have failed.

What is a good way to solve this problem?

----- Edit #1 -----

Following are the lines in the log -

```
[application]  INFO 9 --- [main] o.s.c.f.c.c.SimpleFunctionRegistry : Looking up function ' bean1' with acceptedOutputTypes: []
[application]  DEBUG 9 --- [main] o.s.c.f.c.c.SimpleFunctionRegistry : Failed to discover function ' bean1' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [functionRouter]. This is generally acceptable for cases where there was no intention to use functions.
```

and

```
[application]  WARN 9 --- [main] onConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar : You have defined function definition that does not exist: bean1
```

Comment: Could you add your application starting up logs?

Comment: Are you still using @SpringBootApplication annotation in your main class?

Comment: Yes, I am still using @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: Have you any startup error?

Comment: No, it just starts perfectly fine. It is just that those beans do not work.